# Import data from a row/column of one google sheet, into another sheet based on column value matching exactly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a nutrition tracker to better manage my nutrition. I have it set up as follows.

one sheet is called Foods, this contains columns with the headings
FOOD NAME, CALORIES,   PROTEIN CARBS,  OF WHICH SUGARS,    FAT,    OF WHICH SATURATED,     FIBER,  SALT,

the nutritional values in the Foods sheet are per G.

On sheet 2, called Templates. I have a meal table template with the following columns.

FOOD NAME,  WEIGHT(G),  CALORIES,   PROTEIN CARBS,  OF WHICH SUGARS FATS,   OF WHICH SATURATED,     FIBER,  SALT

I have it so that a drop down list of the column food name in sheet Foods populates the cell for each cell in the food name column of the meal table.

What I want is for each column in the meal table (rows/columns in the sheet Templates) are populated based on the selection from the drop down list and also the inputted weight in g.

to see the issue in a more visual way please see the attached picture.

Im really not sure which function to use or how to populate these cells the way i want to.
[Foods sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn1Zb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nilJf.png)

Comment: Hi, Use a VLOOKUP function. I can help you more if you share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think `vlookup` within an `arrayformula` could work.

Example `FOOD` sheet:

[image]

Clear cells `D10:K:18` on your Template sheet, then paste this into cell `D10`:

`=arrayformula({FOODS!$B$1:$I$1;if(B11:B18<>"",C11:C18/1000*iferror(vlookup(B11:B18,FOODS!$A:$I,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},false),),)})`

[image]

If it helps, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, then I'll add notes :-)